# C# Multi-Subform in Main form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing an industrial program in c#. Since there are too many operations in the program, I placed multiple forms inside the form on the main page. But I cannot make any changes to the Main form using any control in the sub-form. What is the reason? Should I use Invoke?

This is my main form :

```
 private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        frmMeasure frmMeasure = new frmMeasure();
        frmMeasure.TopLevel = false;
        frmMeasure.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmMeasure.Visible = true;
        pnlMain.Controls.Clear();
        pnlMain.Controls.Add(frmMeasure);
   }
```

This is sub-form and not working .

```
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();

        frmProductSettings frmProductSettings = new frmProductSettings();
        frmProductSettings.TopLevel = false;
        frmProductSettings.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmProductSettings.Visible = true;
        frmMain.pnlMain.Controls.Clear();
        frmMain.pnlMain.Controls.Add(frmProductSettings);
    }
```

My aim is to change the sub-forms by using the button in the sub-form that I opened in the main form.
Thank you.

Comment: `frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();` is a complete new object of frmMain. It is not the same as the one you already opened

Comment: I created it in the button event inside the sub-form.
It's not the same, sir. Information is being exchanged between 2 forms. There is a situation here, more than one sub-form is working in the Main form and I want to change the other sub-form by using the button in these sub-forms.

Comment: As already noted… “why” is the code in the “sub” form creating a NEW main form with … `frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();` … ? … and then it is never shown? This same idea would apply to all the forms in your code. `frmMeasure frmMeasure = new frmMeasure();` … and … `frmProductSettings frmProductSettings = new frmProductSettings();` … may well be created, however they are NEVER displayed to the user.

Comment: You did not fully understand the problem,These are Sub-forms.

Comment: See [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). You should use [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for what you call Sub-Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) function to display form inside another form.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

 private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      frmMeasure frmMeasure = new frmMeasure();
      frmMeasure.TopLevel = false;
      frmMeasure.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
      frmMeasure.Visible = true;
      frmMeasure.Show();
      SetParent(frmMeasure.Handle, pnlMain.Handle);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property to get a reference to the main form from within the sub form:

```
// ... from within a sub-form ...
private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmMain main = this.ParentForm as frmMain;
    frmProductSettings frmProductSettings = new frmProductSettings();
    frmProductSettings.TopLevel = false;
    frmProductSettings.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frmProductSettings.Visible = true;
    main.pnlMain.Controls.Clear();
    main.pnlMain.Controls.Add(frmProductSettings);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sir this worked.  it is excatly what I want.